# Proteger código-fonte ASP.NET (aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, segurança, engenharia-de-software

Estou com uma dúvida referente ao ASP.NET:

No caso do PHP ao ser colocado uma aplicação no servidor significa colocar o código fonte do mesmo. Ao caso do ASP.NET, (especificamente C# com páginas em .aspx), existe alguma forma de utilização sem a exposição do código fonte?

Se a aplicação ser somente em C# é possível gerar o executável, mas ao caso do ASP.NET, é possível separar a aplicação funcionando (no cliente, suponhamos) do código fonte?

Comment: Você pode gerar um publish da solution.

Comment: No caso estou utilizando ferramentas free (Visual Studio). Existe esta opção? - Na verdade já programei em C# e estou pensando em começar (seria um retorno) com ASP.NET.

Comment: Acho que sim.Clica com o botão direito em cima do seu projeto. Se ele for Web site Pusblish Web Site

Comment: Você usa Web Forms, correto?

Comment: Você ainda vai iniciar um projeto ou já tem um pronto/em andamento? Se for iniciar, sugiro avaliar a utilização do MVC com o ASP.NET, assim toda a sua lógica fica nos controllers que estão nas DLL, apenas o conteúdo HTML e pouco coisa de código fonte fica disponível, no caso penas `if`, `for`, `foreach` e nada de lógica de negócio.

Answer (score 1):

Para hospedar uma aplicação ASP.NET você deve publicá-la primeiro. Durante a publicação o código fonte é compilado e os arquivos .cs transformados em *DLL's*. Por isso, o código fonte não fica exposto como em PHP.

Dê uma olhada como realizar uma publicação [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/20yh9f1b(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Seu código fonte está em arquivo separado .cs (Code behind) ou está embutido no Aspx ? Em todo caso, como já foi falado, o VisualStudio gera uma DLL por página .aspx, portando seu código fonte está supostamente seguro.

Eu digo supostamente porque é possível descompilar o bytecode da DLL para gerar códio fonte em C#, VB.Net etc

Se você precisa de um nível a mais de segurança, procure soluções de embaralhamento de dll .Net

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET